# Sum all rows wherever cell value meets condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame such as:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2500,1, 1, 1), 
                 col2 = c(12, NA, 8,9, 5), 
                 col3 = c(25, 48, 7, 9, 14))
df
  col1 col2 col3
1    1   12   25
2 2500   NA   48
3    1    8    7
4    1    9    9
5    1    5   14
```

I am hoping to **sum the rows only when cell value is above 1, while ignoring NA values**, to make a data frame like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(col1 = c(2500), 
                         col2 = sum(12, 8,9, 5), 
                         col3 = sum(25, 48, 7, 9, 14))
df_desired
  col1 col2 col3
1 2500   34  103
```

I have gotten this far:

```
df_test <- df %>%
summarise_at(vars(contains("col")), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
df_test
  col1 col2 col3
1 2504   34  103
```

I've tried many variations of `ifelse` with no success. I've so far only found examples of conditional summing across columns and adding a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `summarise` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(),  ~ sum(.x[.x > 1], na.rm = TRUE)))
  col1 col2 col3
1 2500   34  103
```

---

Or in `base R` with `colSums` after `replace`ing the elements that are less than 2 to `NA`

```
colSums(replace(df, df < 2, NA),  na.rm = TRUE)
col1 col2 col3 
2500   34  103
```

Comment: `[.x > 1]` is the key here. Thank you very much @akrun. I had the same idea but I used `.x > 1`

Comment: @TarJae `.x > 1` returns a logical vector, thus the `sum` of it would be just the sum of TRUE values. or you could use `sum(.x * (.x > 1), na.rm = TRUE)` which would make the other values to 0 as `FALSE` is 0

Comment: @akrun I also had this idea too but done slighly differently: `colSums(replace(df, df<=1, 0))`. I suggest you change `NA` to 0 just to make it further concise (if you don't mind).

Comment: @B.ChristianKamgang thanks. i did thought about that, but it will still have an issue with default NAs in the dataset

Comment: @akrun Good point! you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `map_dbl` after setting each 1 to 0 within a `ifelse` statement:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(, ~ifelse(. == 1, 0, .))) %>% 
  map_dbl(~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or without `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(, ~ifelse(. == 1, 0, .))) %>% 
  summarise(across(, ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

```
col1 col2 col3 
2500   34  103
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` function, you solve your problem as follow:

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(x[x>1], na.rm=TRUE))

col1 col2 col3 
2500   34  103
```

or using `summarise` function

```
df |> 
  summarise(across(, ~ sum(.[.>1], na.rm=TRUE)))
  col1 col2 col3
1 2500   34  103
```

Answer (score 1):

in Base R use `colSums`:

```
colSums(df * (df > 1), na.rm = TRUE)

col1 col2 col3 
2500   34  103
```